# VMware VirtualCenter Server service stops

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I'm having a problem with my vCenter server.  Within an hour of a reboot the VMware VirtualCenter Server service stops.  If I restart it… it runs for about an hour, then stops again. 
The following event is registered in the system event log.
The VMware VirtualCenter Server service terminated with service-specific error 2 (0x2).

I'm using SQL2005 Express
It’s a VM, windows 2003 Std, 1vCPU, 4 Gb RAM
Tomcat and SQL are using lots of memory.

This is a similar problem to the many many repsonce you will find on google - but not the same. My service stops about an hour after a clean, successful reboot.

Ideas?

Comment: which version of VC?

Comment: vCenter Vs. 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had basicly out grown SQL Express.  Moved DB to a seperate SQL server (full, not express) solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can [gather](http://www.samplex.org/?p=19) from google, it may be because the VC starts before the SQL server :

- Obtain the service name for your SQL Service – in Registry Editor, browse to HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services and look for entries starting with MSSQL. In all likelyhood, yours will be called either MSSQL or MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS (ignore MSSQLServerADHelper)
- Now browse to HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\vpxd
- Open the REG_MULTI_SZ value called DependOnService
- Add a line called “MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS” (or whatever value you determined above)
- Ensure that the last line in the value is blank

Comment: I can confirm this is a problem that can sometimes happen. I've done the above and the problem for me went away completely.

Comment: This is a similar problem… but not the same. My service stops about an hour after a clean, successful reboot

Comment: Is there anything in the systems logs regarding the stopping ?